# How to suppress g++ errors involving restrict directive?

Tags: c++

My C++ compiler cannot understand the `restrict` directive.

How do I suppress these errors?

```
/usr/include/inttypes.h:271: error: expected ',' or '...' before 'nptr'
```

`usr/include/inttypes.h` contains

```
extern intmax_t strtoimax(const char * restrict nptr, char ** restrict endptr, int base);
```

Compile command:

```
g++ -c -pipe -g -gdwarf-2 -arch x86_64 -Xarch_x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -Wall
-W -D_ISOC99_SOURCE -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE
-DPIC -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -o player.o ../dir/player.cpp
```

Edit:

```
$ g++ --version
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.9.00)
```

Comment: What version of GCC is this? Neither 4.5.x on Cygwin nor 4.1.x on Linux give me any troubles...

Comment: Added g++ version info to the question. I am using OS X Lion

Comment: I see the `-mmacosx-version-min=10.5` tidbit in there... if memory serves correctly, MacOS has a special version of llvm-gcc installed, which has some trickeries of its own involved. Check that the compiler you are calling is indeed /usr/bin/g++-4.2 (or whatever is your version), and see if your problem persists. (Edit: Gotcha. That isn't a "real" GCC you're using. ;-) )

Comment: Are you forcing conformance to C99 standard while compiling C++? Try to use something more relaxed such as a `-std=gnu++0x` so that you can use C99 specific features such as `restrict`/`<inttypes.h>` in C++.

Comment: @dirkgently, you can't tell G++ to conform to C99 while compiling C++, that isn't possible. G++ never accepts `restrict` even in C++11 mode. But see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

G++ doesn't support the `restrict` keyword, which is valid in C but not C++.

It *does* support `__restrict__` as an extension, so you could compile with `-Drestrict=__restrict__` to use the preprocessor to turn it into the accepted keyword.

See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Restricted-Pointers.html for details.

The issue seems to be caused by your use of `-DISOC99_SOURCE` which doesn't seem to be compatible with C++ on your OS, since it enables C99 features that are not valid in C++.  On GNU/Linux I would suggest using `-D_GNU_SOURCE` instead, but I doubt that works on Mac OS X.

So instead of `-Drestrict=__restrict__` you could just stop using `-D_ISOC99_SOURCE` -- why do you even need that for C++?

Comment: Strange... when I tried it, the g++ compiler didn't complain at all (see my comment to OP).

Comment: @DevSolar, did you use `-D_ISOC99_SOURCE` so the system headers use the `restrict` keyword?

Comment: Ahhhhh... gotcha. That's what you get for thinking, "I don't need to copy all that command line cruft to check this". Good catch.

Comment: Spot on. ISOC99_SOURCE, which crept in from some old Makefile, has now retired too. Thanks